# How to set attributes in pandasdmx

Tags: python, pandas, sdmx

The "pandasdmx" [documentation](https://pandasdmx.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0/walkthrough.html) has an example of how to set dimensions, but no how to set attributes.
I tried passing "key" to the variable, but an error occurs.
Perhaps setting attributes requires a different syntax?
At the end of my sample code, I printed out a list of dimensions and attributes.

```
import pandasdmx as sdmx
import pandas as pd

ecb = sdmx.Request('ECB')
key = dict(FREQ=['M'], SEC_ITEM=['F51100'], REF_AREA = ['I8'], SEC_ISSUING_SECTOR = ['1000'])
params = dict(startPeriod='2010-02', endPeriod='2010-02')
data_msg = ecb.data('SEC', key=key, params=params)

data = data_msg.data[0]
daily = [s for sk, s in data.series.items() if sk.FREQ == 'M']
cur_df = pd.concat(sdmx.to_pandas(daily)).unstack()
print(cur_df.to_string())

flow_msg = ecb.dataflow()
dataflows = sdmx.to_pandas(flow_msg.dataflow)
exr_msg = ecb.dataflow('SEC')
exr_flow = exr_msg.dataflow.SEC
dsd = exr_flow.structure

dimen = dsd.dimensions.components
attrib = dsd.attributes.components
print(dimen)
print(attrib)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, what you're asking here is not “how to *set* attributes” but “how to include attributes when converting (or ‘writing’) an SDMX DataSet to a pandas DataFrame”.

Using [`sdmx1`](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io/),¹ see the documentation for the *attribute* parameter to the [`write_dataset()` function](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sdmx.writer.pandas.write_dataset). This is the function that is ultimately called by `to_pandas()` when you pass a DataSet object as the first argument.

In your sample code, the key line is:

```py
sdmx.to_pandas(daily)
```

You might try instead:

```py
sdmx.to_pandas(data_msg.data[0], attributes="dsgo")
```

Per the documentation, the string `"dsgo"` means “include in additional columns all attributes attached at the **d**ataset, **s**eries key, **g**roup, and **o**bservation levels.”

---

¹ `sdmx1` is a fork of `pandaSDMX` with many enhancements and more regular releases.

Comment: Thanks.  If I understand correctly when connecting the module "sdmx1", it is not necessary to specify sdmx1: import pandasdmx as sdmx?

Comment: `sdmx1` is the name used on PyPI (because `sdmx` was already taken, by a package that's unmaintained). So to install, e.g. `pip install sdmx1`.

Once installed, use `import sdmx` instead of `import pandasdmx`. The latter package is not needed.